# Can the word "that" mean "because" in some contexts?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read an example in "Merriam Webster dictionaries" which was:

The trout population in the stream is burgeoning now that the water is clean.

I think the word "that" has been used to mean "because" in this context. But I wanted to ask whether it is necessarily  preceded by "now" to be understood that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> This construction is fine: The subject (reason) is appropriately linked (by the linking verb is) to the noun phrase

Please follow [this article](https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/reason-because-or-reason-that/) answering your question.